cannot find IWebHostEnvironment in any assembly
I just upgraded to ASP.NET Core 8 and now the compiler can't find IWebHostEnvironment.
In what assembly is it?
IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }


It should be in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll

There's no reason or excuse for asking this question here. Just open the API reference documentation and search for that type. The documentation page for every type tells you what namepsace it's a member of and what assembly it's declared in. I was able to find the answer to your question in less than 5 seconds. If you didn't know that the documentation provided that information then that's a problem in and of itself, because someone with your rep score has been doing this long enough that they should be well acquainted with the documentation by now.

@jmcilhinney I wasn't looking for an excuse, I tried to follow the assembly name but it didn't work so I asked here. that's what you do on stackoverflow right?

What you do on SO is provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the specific problem you're having, not ask questions to which you already know the answer. If you know what assembly that type is defined in the you don't need an answer to the question you actually asked, so you should have asked the question you actually needed an answer to.

@jmcilhinney I'm sorry but I can't see what I did wrong. I added the correct packages, but still same issue, so I was stuck and needed a solution, so I posted here. You may think it was wrong, but I don't. Instead of using several hours to fix a small thing I asked here and got an answer in minutes. you're off course free to ignore my post

Which version you upgraded  from? Less than .net core 3.0 ? Normally,  this dll is working after .net core 3.0. Besides, after adding the dll or reference , do you solve the issue?

I solve the initial issue, but now I'm having some trouble adding project references. I didn't upgrade, the issues began when I created new projects (ASP.NET Core 8)

The fact that you're having to provide additional information in comments should make it clear that your question is inadequate as asked. You say that you added all the right packages but you didn't say that in your question and we don't know what you think the right packages are. You say you created a new project but your question said you upgraded, so that's misleading. It's not hard to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of you try. That you don't see what's wrong with the question is part of the problem.

The fact that you're having to provide additional information in comments should make it clear that your question is inadequate as asked. You say that you added all the right packages but you didn't say that in your question and we don't know what you think the right packages are. You say you created a new project but your question said you upgraded, so that's misleading. It's not hard to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of you try. That you don't see what's wrong with the question is part of the problem.

how much clearer can I be. In which assembly is IWebhostEnvironment. seems pretty clear to me

@jmcilhinney if you were to open the linked documentation before being rude, you'd see that it doesn't give any useful information about actually adding it to your project.

@jmcilhinney part of the problem? what problem? My question was sufficient to get a correct  answer so I'm happy with it. BUT whatever, have a nice day

To add this to your project, you should use a FrameworkReference.
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

